# Accurate results joining 2 tables

Tags: mysql

Table A lists an item and the number of pieces that must go through each of the 4 possible stations.

```
Item      To Cut      To Paste      To Laminate      To Ship
Box          9            9              5              9
Cart         1            0              10             10
```

Table B lists the number of pieces that have been processed through each of the stations.

```
Item      Cut Done      Paste Done      Laminated      Shipped
Box          9            0                0             0
Box          0            9                0             0
Box          0            0                5             0
Box          0            0                0             9
```

When I join them it shows:

```
Item      To Cut      Cut Done      To Paste      Paste Done
Box          36          9             36             9
```

This is because of the way Table B works. How can I get it to accurately show the total To Cut and Cut Done in one table so percentages are correct?

My query is:

```
select a.item, a.to_cut, a.to_paste, a.to_laminate, a.to_ship, b.cut_done, b.paste_done, b.laminated, b.shipped

from ToDo a join Done b on a.item = b.item
```

Comment: please, add your current query.

Comment: Added it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a subquery with the calculated sums.

```
select tableA.Item, To_Cut, To_Paste, To_Laminate, To_Ship, d.Cut_Done, d.Paste_Done, d.Laminated, d.Shipped
from tableA 
inner join (select Item, 
                   sum(Cut_Done) as Cut_Done,
                   sum(Paste_Done) as Paste_Done,
                   sum(Laminated) as Laminated,
                   sum(Shipped) as Shipped
            from   tableB
            group by Item) d
on tableA.Item = d.Item;

| Item | To_Cut | To_Paste | To_Laminate | To_Ship | Cut_Done | Paste_Done | Laminated | Shipped |
|-----:|--------|----------|-------------|---------|----------|------------|-----------|---------|
| Box  | 9      | 9        | 5           | 9       | 9        | 9          | 5         | 0       |
```

Rextester [here](http://rextester.com/YFJ58149)

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick help with this.

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.